# Add class with numbers to each li elements, jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, each, addclass

Add class with numbers to each li elements, jquery.

***Here is a sample of my code:***

```
$('li').each(function(i) {

$(this).addClass(i);

});
```

There is a way to add class only with numbers, i know i am able to add class with this way `$(this).addClass('something'+i);` but instead i want only with numbers like:

```
<li class='1'></li>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead od `$(this).addClass(i);` try using `$(this).addClass(i.toString());`

But, having numbers as class names will get you into trouble... I just demonstrated how you can do this with jQuery.

Comment: Its exactly what i want, thank you very much kosturko :)

Answer (score 0):

Classname must begin with a letter. Numbers as class name are illegal in the CSS grammar.

**[See this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=277768)**

You can use the below hack to add the class number but you can not set the css for such class names:

```
$('li').each(function(i) {
 $(this).attr('class',i);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KjE3g/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(i) {
 $(this).attr('class','section-'+i);
 i++;
});
```

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass('class_name_'+i);
  i++;
});
```